# Can I create a file that sits next to a .Designer.cs file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio, two files are created when you create a new Windows Form in your solution (e.g. if you create MyForm.cs, MyForm.Designer.cs and MyForm.resx are also created). These second two files are displayed as a subtree in the Solution Explorer.

**Is there any way to add files to the sub-tree or group for a Windows Form class?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open .csproj in edit mode, look for the file you want to be under another one, and add the DependentUpon element, like this:

```
<Compile Include="AlertDialog.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>AlertDialog.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: The FileNesting extension can do that automatically: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit the csproj directly. There is a DependentUpon tag that you have to add as a child tag of the file you want to place under MyForm.cs.

Example:

```
<Compile Include="MyForm.MyCoolSubFile.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it's a bit of a hassle - basically you need to edit the project file by hand.

Here's an example from a project that Marc Gravell and I both work on:

```
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExt.cs" />
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExt.SingleReturn.cs">
  <DependentUpon>DataProducerExt.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExt.Grouping.cs">
  <DependentUpon>DataProducerExt.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExt.Pipeline.cs">
  <DependentUpon>DataProducerExt.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExt.Conversion.cs">
  <DependentUpon>DataProducerExt.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExt.Math.cs">
  <DependentUpon>DataProducerExt.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Note the "DependentUpon" element in each of the dependencies. This displays appropriately in VS, with DataProducerExt.cs as the parent.