# .less files with .css subfiles

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

I was wondering on how this file structure was done.

[image]

I know how to use dotless, but I don't know how make compiled files under .less file.
Any Idea?

**Edit**

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223249/can-i-create-a-file-that-sits-next-to-a-designer-cs-file-in-visual-studio)

And I had an idea that, if I would be able to make every .css file sits next to .less file using `<DependentUpon>` tag, then it could work.

I've been following this [tutorial](http://richardneililagan.com/2012/08/automatic-dotless-compile-less-css/) regarding dotless

And I think the solution could be done here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/MsBuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CompileDotlessCss">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Binaries Include="*.dll;*.exe"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Compile dotLess CSS into minified full CSS -->
    <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)..\[MSBuild]\dotless.Compiler.exe $(ProjectDir)..\css\main.css $(ProjectDir)..\css\main.min.css -m"/>

  </Target>
</Project>
```

But I don't know how.. Please help!

**Edit 2**

I think I need to change the question.
So my new question would be, "How can I automatically include generated files using the `Exec` command in the project, and make those generate .css files as a subfiles of the target .less file?"

**Edit 3**

Hmmm.. my question could be so confusing to others.. I've found this [video](http://screencast.com/t/eNvT0FI2WAni) on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176675/visual-studio-precompile-dotless#7224589) and that is what I want. Generate .css files from .less files and make .css file as subfiles of .less, and make it included in the project automatically! But using MSBuild.. Is this possible? Please help! :-)

**Edit Final**

Okay.. After I read the documentation and use this [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)
I realize that, I was doing the old thing above.
So, I don't need to do those stuff above, its all done using web essentials..

So the answer for my question is, to use Web Essentials.

Comment: You could take a look at how Visual Studio 2012 does it (or WebEssentials if you have 2010). It comes out of the box for 2012

Comment: @Kenneth Honestly, I don't have idea on how to do that. I'm just new to MSBuild. Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176675/visual-studio-precompile-dotless/13607390?noredirect=1#answer-13607390 I think the answer could be found here.

Comment: @Kenneth Thanks! I got the idea now.. Kindly see my final edit..

Answer (score 0):

As I think you discovered, Web Essentials can do this automatically.  It can also then bundle the generated CSS files into a single file, which is pretty handy too.

http://vswebessentials.com/